# How to send a child node id and display its contents from local JSON file in Quasar Tree

Tags: vue.js, qtreeview, quasar-framework, qtreewidgetitem

I want to display a Tree View and I have 4 local JSON files, when I click on the first node I want to send that node id and then display its respective child items from another JSON file and then when I click on the child item I want to send that child item id to and then display its content from another JSON file.

I want the functionality to be like this

[image]

can anyone please help me with this?